# ng2 fileupload is not working in angular7?

Tags: angular, types, ng2-file-upload

I have an `angular8` app in which i want to send file on server.I am using `ng2-file-upload`.

Here is my component.ts

```
import { FileUploader, FileLikeObject } from 'ng2-file-upload';

const URL = `${environment.api_base_url}/files`; 

public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
  url: URL,
  disableMultipart : false,
  autoUpload: true,
  method: 'post',
  itemAlias: 'file',
  allowedFileType: ['pdf', 'csv']
});

public onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
  const file: File = event[0];
  console.log(file);
}
```

In `component.html` i have this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-submit btn-block mb-1" (click)="fileInput.click()">Upload Customer CSV</button>
<input type="file"  class="d-none"  id="csvFileUpload" #fileInput ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

Now `http` `post` request it is not sending in network tab when i select any file. It only prints console that is in `onFileSelected` function. It prints file object.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? I am facing the same problem...